# Devices in eclipse layout view

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

My wife and I have been working on this single lay out for hours. Whenever we get it to look right in the layout view it doesnt display the same on our phones. (note 3 and S4)

The devices listed in the dropdown in the layout view are older devices is there anyway to see what the view would look like on a note 3 or s4 in the graphical layout view?

I dont see an option for adding a new or custom device.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse layout tool has never worked right.  It gets close on simple layouts, but it can't handle complex ones or custom views.  Don't trust it, and don't try to treat it as a WYSIWYG tool.  You need to actually learn the xml language for making layouts and how to do it right, and test it on an actual device(s) or emulators.  There is no substitute for that.

Answer (score 1):

As was already said Eclipse's preview windows doesn't really work that well. 
If you want to have a real fast preview of your layout on a real device without compiling and starting your app every time, I can't recomment [Jimu Mirror](http://jimulabs.com/) enough.

Answer (score 0):

To test how layouts and apps function in real different devices, the best emulator I found is Genymotion: http://www.genymotion.com/

It is easy to setup and super fast. You will never use the native emulator again.